# Chromium Kiosk Script Hangs Without Peripherals Plugged In

Tags: boot, bash, chromium

I'm setting up a Pi Zero W to run a script on boot to run a Chromium kiosk with a specific URL, refreshing the page every 5 minutes. Initially everything worked great. I tested it over multiple reboots and the script worked flawlessly.

Satisfied with the setup, I began another reboot and removed the USB hub which had two wireless dongles for a mouse/keyboard plugged in to ensure that everything still worked without any input/peripherals, as it's meant to be a wall display. This time, it booted into the desktop and then sat idle with very little CPU load, no script activity. It sat this way for a few minutes until I plugged in the hub again to investigate, at which point the script immediately ran and worked fine. I've tested this a few times and it consistently works with at least one dongle plugged in (mouse or keyboard), but never without. After 20-30 minutes, the script does eventually work without the peripherals.

I'm at a loss as to what's causing this. I followed the steps/scripts in this article except that I'm using xdotool to do a periodic refresh rather than change tabs: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-kiosk/

Does something in my script require a physical peripheral, or is Raspbian waiting on a peripheral before it fires off my script?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms

unclutter -idle 0.5 -root &

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk https:REDACTED &

while true; do
   xdotool keydown ctrl+r; xdotool keyup ctrl+r;
   sleep 300
done
```

Running from the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Chromium Kiosk
Wants=graphical.target
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/kiosk.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

If I check the status of the script while it's hanging, I get the following:

```
Jun 03 08:20:06 ConferenceScreen systemd[1]: Started Chromium Kiosk.
Jun 03 08:20:06 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: xset:  unable to open display ":0"
Jun 03 08:20:11 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxset:
Jun 03 08:20:11 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxset:
Jun 03 08:20:11 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyunclut
Jun 03 08:20:11 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError:
Jun 03 08:20:11 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Failed creating new xdo instance
Jun 03 08:20:12 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError:
Jun 03 08:20:12 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Failed creating new xdo instance
Jun 03 08:20:24 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: : getrandom indicates that the entropy pool has not been initialized. Rather than continue with poor entropy, this process will block until entropy is available.
```

After everything finally starts, it adds:

```
Jun 03 08:29:52 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
Jun 03 08:29:57 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: [443:1219:0603/082957.316700:ERROR:bus.cc(396)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
Jun 03 08:30:11 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Jun 03 08:30:16 ConferenceScreen bash[351]: [1:8:0603/083016.742760:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(124)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuChannelMsg_CreateCommandBuffer.
```

Comment: How should we know what your script does?

Comment: Sorry, the script and service are in the link, but I've added them to the post as well.

Comment: The script needs the X server. Does the X server start without the USB hub? Can you connect via LAN so that you can see whether the script runs? Otherwise, look at the log for hints.

Comment: I can certainly SSH in without the hub, but I confess I have no idea how to check if the X server is running. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: what do you see on the screen during the 20-30 minute delay?

Comment: After the initial boot activity, it sits idle on the empty desktop. The CPU meter holds steady at 0-2%. I'd love to know what the script is doing at this point but I've got no idea how to check that.

Comment: I was able to remotely check the status of the script when it's hanging. I added the errors I saw in the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else is running into this, I finally figured out that it's hanging on the lack of entropy. Apparently without a mouse/keyboard or any activity, it takes a long time to generate enough entropy for random to function. Running

```
sudo apt-get install rng-tools
```

Completely resolved the issue for me.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Since Raspbian Stretch 2019-04-08 **rng-tools** are installed by default. If you use Raspbian it is always a good idea to do `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` from time to time.

Comment: I bought a kit and used whatever came loaded on the SD card with NOOBS, I'll run some updates, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Raspbian 12 (bookworm) doesn't install rng-tools by default either. You have to choose from *rng-tools-debian* and *rng-tools5*.